# How do I change a string in a for loop

Tags: visual-c++

So i'm trying to make the variable "name" equal "slider1" but it gives me 
the error

> initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object

the code:

```
for (int TpNum = 1; TpNum < 2; TpNum++)
{
    char name[8] = ("slider" + TpNum );

    Enemy name(5, 5, 'r', name);
}
```

Comment: you masu cascading `TpNum ` to char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are aggregate types, and as such are initialized with an [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

More spurious is your attempt to add `char*`s. You should use C++ `std::string`s, but here's how you can accomplish it with C strings.

```
for (int TpNum = 1; TpNum < 2; ++TpNum)
{
    char[8] name; 
    sprintf(name,"slider%d",TpNum);

    Enemy name(5, 5, 'r', name);
}
```

You'll need to include `<stdio.h>` to use `sprintf`.

**EDIT**

Also note that your loop will only execute once, so you could just say

```
Enemy name(5, 5, 'r', "slider1");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, and i'm sorry if I didn't provide enough context.